# PagesPrinted field of job_info_2 not reliable for hp printers on windows 7, value depends on print processor

Tags: printing, windows-7, driver, print-spooler-api

PagesPrinted field of job_info_2 not reliable for hp printers on windows 7, value depends on print processor

I'm developping a print monitor, and for hp printer PagesPrinted is not reliable et has wrong values

Comment: Something is calling SetJob with incorrect values in that field.  Most likely that would be the driver.  But since a port monitor is responsible for transmitting printer data to the printer, it should be able to determine the number of pages on its own.  However, I don't understand what your question actually is.

Comment: when I Print a pdf document  : document of 2 pages, 2 pages per sheet, and 3 copies, in notification I receive TotalPages = 1 (right value )  and PagesPrinted = 3 (wrong value, it should be 1 as described in msdn and as sent for others printer Lexmark, Xerox... ), the printer is shared on a windows 7 and used on another windows 7

Comment: and when I repeat the same test PagesPrinted = 12, 24 and always TotalPages = 1 (right value ) it's not reliable as field with Hp printers, I haven't this case with other types of printers

Comment: I use this API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162861(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: EnumPrinters, OpenPrinter, FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification, WaitForMultipleObjects, WaitForSingleObject, FindNextPrinterChangeNotification : that's is my call sequence of windows functions

Comment: I'm afraid this is likely a bug in the HP print driver.  A print driver shouldn't be calling SetJob at all, but it looks like it probably is.  Frankly, HP print drivers are some of the most buggiest drivers out there.

Comment: I agree, I think it's, a bug in the HP print driver, the solution would be to use TotalPages instead of PagesPrinted

Comment: or find why on windows seven the problem apear

Comment: how can I know if PagesPrinted was set by driver or not?

Comment: You would have to either attach a debugger to the spooler service (spoolsv.exe) and set a breakpoint on SetJob, or use a tool like [APIMonitor](http://www.apimonitor.com/).  The trouble is, it's quite likely that many components running under the spooler service will call SetJob, so determining that it's the HP driver doing it might be difficult.  But does it really matter which component is doing it?  Something other than your code is resetting that member and I doubt you can do anything about it.

Comment: thanks Carey, Yes, in fact it doesn't really matter which component is changing this field, but I want to how to stop changing it or how to get the right value of printed page

Comment: I don't know how you could stop someone else's driver from changing it.  And without that, I don't know how you could get the correct value from GetJob.  What type of printer is it?  If it's Postscript, the page count is in the data stream, so you could just parse the Postscript stream for it.

Comment: Hp printer deskjet f4200 series used with "Hp printer deskjet f4200 series" driver and Hp UPD 5.2 driver

Comment: That printer is PCL, not Postscript.  You can still parse the data stream to get a page count; it's just not as easy as Postscript.

Answer (score 1):

The print driver for your printer is apparently calling SetJob with incorrect page count values.  There's probably nothing you can do about that.  Therefore, the only way to get an accurate page count is to parse the print data stream and count the pages yourself.  The printer in question uses PCL.  Fortunately, there is an open source [PCL viewer](http://openpcl.sourceforge.net/) available from sourceforge, which you can use to parse the PCL.  Although this solution is more complex than simply calling GetJob, it should work reliably for all PCL printers.  Supporting Postscript printers can be done in a similar manner, and the parsing is much simpler since Postscript puts the page count directly in the data stream.